# How to remove all git file except .gitignore

Tags: git

I want to remove all git related files in project except .gitignore file. The commands I found about git remove will remove everything, but most of the time I still need gitignore

How would you do that?

Comment: You can copy `.gitignore` and then delete everything then paste it back!

Comment: Delete everything and then git checkout `.gitignore` back from the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rm -rf .git
```

This remove all git file except git ignore

Answer (score 0):

You can set a environment in order to ignore special file patterns for the `*`

For example:

```
GLOBIGNORE='.git*'
git rm *
```

so it won't remove any files that starts with `.git`

[More info on GLOBIGNORE](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-GLOBIGNORE)

However, if you want to ignore every dot file you can have a look at [dotglob](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html)

```
# set dotglob
shopt -s dotglob

git rm *

# unset dotglob
shopt -u dotglob
```